# Aver M780 ngene firmware no longer creating /dev/dvb

Tags: drivers, kernel-modules, firmware, modprobe, dvb

After a sudden restart of my server by a power failure (that my battery backup didn't catch), my tv tuner cards are no longer working. The `/dev/dvb` is not being automatically created. Everything has been working perfectly fine for years. I have not recently updated, I'm on debian 10 (buster).

```
dpkg --list | grep linux-image
rc  linux-image-4.19.0-5-amd64  4.19.37-5+deb10u2  amd64  Linux 4.19 for 64-bit PCs (signed)
rc  linux-image-4.19.0-6-amd64  4.19.67-2+deb10u2  amd64  Linux 4.19 for 64-bit PCs (signed)
rc  linux-image-4.19.0-8-amd64  4.19.98-1+deb10u1  amd64  Linux 4.19 for 64-bit PCs (signed)
ii  linux-image-4.19.0-9-amd64  4.19.118-2+deb10u1 amd64  Linux 4.19 for 64-bit PCs (signed)
```

```
sudo journalctl --boot | grep -iE "dvb|ngene"
kernel: ngene: nGene PCIE bridge driver, Copyright (C) 2005-2007 Micronas
kernel: ngene 0000:06:00.0: Found Aver M780 ATSC/QAM-B
kernel: ngene 0000:06:00.0: Device version 1
kernel: ngene 0000:06:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware ngene_15.fw
kernel: ngene 0000:06:00.0: No LGDT330x found!
kernel: ngene 0000:03:00.0: Found Aver M780 ATSC/QAM-B
kernel: ngene 0000:03:00.0: Device version 1
kernel: ngene 0000:03:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware ngene_15.fw
kernel: ngene 0000:03:00.0: No LGDT330x found!
```

```
lsmod | grep dvb
dvb_core 147456 2 lgdt330x,ngene
```

```
sudo dmesg | egrep -i '(firmware|atsc|dvb)'
[    0.688713] pci 0000:00:00.0: [Firmware Bug]: reg 0x1c: invalid BAR (can't size)
[    9.444961] ngene 0000:06:00.0: Found Aver M780 ATSC/QAM-B
[    9.479046] ngene 0000:06:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware ngene_15.fw
[    9.665568] ngene 0000:03:00.0: Found Aver M780 ATSC/QAM-B
[    9.665903] ngene 0000:03:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware ngene_15.fw
```

ngene_15.fw, ngene_16.fw, ngene_17.fw and ngene_18.fw are listed in `/lib/firmware`

I always do a restart if a new kernel image is updated so I don't believe I had a pending update that replaced the kernel so I wouldn't think that a new kernel image dropped support for my ngene firmware.

`sudo modprobe lgdt330x` and `sudo modprobe ngene` doesn't do anything. However trying `modprobe ngene_15` reports:

```
sudo modprobe ngene_15
modprobe: FATAL: Module ngene_15 not found in directory /lib/modules/4.19.0-9-amd64
```

Comment: Multiple restarts did not fix the problem. However when the power was interrupted again and the UPS did not protect the server, it fixed the problem and it works again as before. It makes no sense why a power outage would fix a problem a restart wouldn't but there it is. UPS's are now fixed so hopefully the problem doesn't occur again.